# php dynamic list of SQL array - how to set order?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list

I have a custom web store and it was made with php. It gets all my products from certain categories that are stored in a mySQL database, and displays them in tables for my customers. The programming looks like it is meant to sort them by date added, but that doesn't work. I have messed with it several times trying different variables with no help. Is there something wrong with the syntax here?

This is the code for the actual list (above the  on the page):

```
$dynamicList = "";
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 5");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
   $category = $_GET['category'];
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$category'");
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
   if($num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
         $product_name = $row["product_name"];
         $price = $row["price"];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         $dynamicList .= '<table width="65%" border="15" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="17%" valign="top"><a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img style="border:#000000 1px solid;" src="inventory_images/' . $id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name . '" width="155" height="155" border="1" /></a></td>
      <td width="83%" valign="center">' . $product_name . '<br />
        $' . $price . '<br />
        <a href="product.php?id=' . $id . '"><img src="style/detailssm.png" border="0" alt="Tube Bender"></a></td>
    </tr>
  </table>';
  }
 }
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

My product database has all the attributes listed in the code above, and they are all filled out (like product_name, date_added, category, etc). I would really like to be able to get the sort by date to work, or add a new column like "display order" and then I just number them all and be done with it. But I can't just replace the variable since the current one doesn't work anyway : (

Let me know if you guys have any ideas. Thank you!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 sql statements in your sample code. The first has an ORDER BY clause, but doesn't appear to be used anywhere.

The second SQL statement has no ORDER BY clause, and that's the one you use to build your dynamicList table.

Comment: Oh... thank you. I am so sick of things getting deprecated. what is the new way to order lists in PHP/mySQL?

Comment: @user1570409 There is not a new way to order lists.  It is just your second query (the one actually used) doesn't have an `ORDER BY` clause.  The comments about deprecation have to do with the fact you are using `mysql_*` functions which have been deprecated.  It is recommended to use mysqli, PDO, or other modern database libraries which support prepared statements.

Comment: Deleted the top one, added order to the bottom one. It will work until they stop browser support I guess : )

Answer (score 0):

I think that the second query just to have the "order by", try this...

```
<?php 

     $dynamicList = "";
     $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC LIMIT 5");
     $productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount

     if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
        $category = $_GET['category'];
                 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '$category' ORDER BY date_added DESC ");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
      ...

?>
```

Comment: Yep, this worked. I guess if you look at your code long enough you can't find the obvious line that is doing nothing!